Confusion regarding terraform state file
My understanding of the state file is that terraform remembers what resources it provisioned.
Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't this assume only terraform is managing the resource ?  You cannot guarantee a user will not make changes to the resource from the UI, or rest API.
Or am I missing something ?

This is probably a better question for the Hashicorp Discuss website.

Terraform stores information about your infrastructure in a state file. This state file keeps track of resources created by your configuration and maps them to real-world resources.
Terraform uses state to determine which changes to make to your infrastructure. Prior to any operation, Terraform does a refresh to update the state with the real infrastructure.
Manual changes to the infrastructure
When you run terraform plan, Terraform compares the current state file with the actual infrastructure and the Terraform configuration files. If someone has made manual changes to the infrastructure that Terraform is managing, these changes will be detected during the terraform plan operation.
When you run terraform apply, Terraform will attempt to make the actual infrastructure match the desired state defined in the Terraform configuration files:

If the manual change is consistent with the Terraform configuration, Terraform will not make any changes to that resource. The state file will be updated to reflect the manual change.

If the manual change is not consistent with the Terraform configuration, Terraform will undo the manual change.


Recommended reading:

Terraform state
Manage resources in Terraform state

